# trouble understanding Moser theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Moser's theorem state's that

> Given a closed connected $n$-dimensionnal manifold $M$ and two volume forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\int_M\alpha = \int_M\beta$, then there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi^*\alpha = \beta$.

The proof goes as follows:

$\alpha-\beta$ is of integral $0$ so there exists a $\gamma\in\Omega^{n-1}(M)$ such that $d\gamma = \alpha-\beta$. (Now the part I don't get) There exists also a Vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $\text{int}(X)\alpha = -\gamma$ where $\text{int}()$ is the interior derivative.

Why does such a $X$ exist?

Comment: There is probably a more direct route, but one path is via Riemannian geometry: if you choose a metric such that $\alpha$ is the Riemannian volume form, then $X = - (\star \gamma)^\sharp$ does the job.

Comment: what is the $\sharp$ and the $\star$?

Comment: Musical isomorphism and Hodge star respectively. If you're not already familiar with these concepts then it might not be the easiest way to proceed.

Comment: it sounds very cool but I've never heard of it.

Comment: OK, we should try something more elementary. Can you solve this problem in a single coordinate patch, where $\alpha = f dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n$?

Comment: Not really no. Unless it's just simply Cauchy's existence of solutions of differential equations. As I write this down, I think that I should work very well.

Comment: Well, the problem of solving $i_X\alpha=-\gamma$ for $X$ isn't a differential equation: it's just a linear equation at each point. If you write out this equation in terms of coordinate components of arbitrary $X,\alpha,\gamma$ then you should be able to find an explicit smooth local solution very easily. To get a global solution, you can glue local solutions using a partition of unity.

Comment: got the idea, thanks